# react native how to memoize inline function

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to memoize a button if anyone click it.

I heard this creates a new Instance which is bad:

```
onPress={() => makeData('hello')}
```

So I should make it like this:

```
onPress={makeData}
```

But I have to pass a Parameter so I have to do this in the first example.
So what I can do now to memoized it ? its creates every time a new instance.

Comment: where is the problem? if you have a function 
```const makeData = () => console.log('hello');```
and when you click each time it logs, where is the problem ?
you should memorize your function when you pass it as props to other components which has many items and so when you click this button it should render only the clicked item.

Comment: How I memoize my function ? With callback?